# How do I modify my x data to be a specific length without slicing in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have some x data and y data which I want to plot.
My x data looks like this:
`[326,406,406,449,491,491,1353,1353,2379,2379, ...]`

the corrosponding y data looks like this:

`[3.46,3.48,3.48,3.48,3.49,3.49,3.49,3.49,3.49,3.49, ...]`

Imagine I want to modify my x data in such a way that it is of fixed length.
But simply slicing like this for exmaple: `x = x(1:100)` would not be good, because then I would also loose the data after the 100th x data point.
I need it to be this way: Having x data as an array of fixed length but also modifying y data in such a way that I don't see a difference when I plot y vs x (except for the fact that x now has a different length and different values, e.g. from 1:100).
I hope you understand what I'm trying to do. I was playing around with interp1 but sadly I did not achieve anything useful.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
For better illustration:
Imagine my y vs. x data looks like this:
[image]

My goal is to simple modify my x and y data in such a way that the x data would range from 1:100 for example, but the curve would still be looking the same.

So basically: Sampling the data

Comment: `interp1` is the right tool. What did you try? I suggest you start with its documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem like this:

```
x_new = linspace(min(x_data), max(x_data), number_of_x_points);
y_new = interp1(x_data, y_data, x_new, 'linear');
```